# How many times can you ask a question that uses a similiar premise?

Tags: discussion, support, writing-style

I asked a question that has already received multiple responses. I am using a similiar premise, but changed the question entirely to the point that the answers given are no longer valid. Is it better to simply post another question or continously edit the current one?

Comment: If it would invalidate answers please refrain from editing and ask a new question. You can test it first in the Sandbox if you would like feedback.

Comment: +1 for asking instead of [chameleoning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745).

Answer (score 7):

### Better to post a new one

Please be respectful of respondent's time. If you invalidate their answers then it shows disrespect or at least disregard for the time they invested in your question. Be kind.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to Green's answer, your new question should link the old question and explain what the differences are. Otherwise some poeple might think it's a duplicate.

Comment: How would I link a question?

Comment: @Shardmartin Just put a link to the original question (you can get the link by hovering over the share button and copying the address) somewhere in your new question, preferably at the top. This then automatically puts it in the right hand bar as a linked question too.